# Android banner adview says required xml attribute adsize was missing

Tags: android, admob

There is a major conflict between admob documentation and admob sdk itself.

Don't take me wrong, I know exactly how to place ads in my apps and I've it working fine for a very long time, but it bugs me off that the documentation states something that clearly doesn't work.

on https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner it is said:

> Warning: Make sure you set the ad size and ad unit ID in the same
> manner (i.e. set both in XML or both programmatically).

I've never understood why to place such a stupid restriction in the library, but lets just acept it.

The short sentence clearly says that `adunit_id` and `adsize` must be set in the same portion of code... NOT SAYING ANYTHING ELSE ABOUT THE OTHER FIELDS

So anyone can conclude from this short sentence that one can declare the adview like:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/basicBannerAdview"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and later on in the code do:

```
    final AdView bannerAdView = findViewById(R.id.basicBannerAdview);
                 bannerAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
                bannerAdView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-2944323778834513/2840086720");
                bannerAdView.loadAd(AdMobRequestUtil.buildAdRequest(loc, Collections.emptySet()).build());
                 bannerAdView.resume();
                bannerAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

this is a very simple code, that should work fine according to the documentation. **BUT IT DOESN'T**

Instead it creates a banner in the right size and format with the words:

```
required xml attribute adsize was missing
```

Am i crazy or google just not able to write a documentation that matches the real library

Answer (score 2):

> Warning: Make sure you set the ad size and ad unit ID in the same manner (i.e. set both in XML or both programmatically).

Admob documentation hasn't clearly stated. But, you cannot set banner ad's `adSize` or `adUnitId` programmatically, if you are declaring it in `XML` and vice versa. You must have to set these two attributes, exactly wherever you are declaring them.

For setting `adUnitId` and `adSize` programmatically, you must have to create `bannerAd` programmatically and add it to your layout.

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
parentLayout.addView(adView)
```

Otherwise, declare the whole adView inside the `XML` layout.